# Angular Circular Dependency Detected between Two Components

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, circular-dependency

There seems to be a circular dependency between two components I am trying to use, with one being injected in and the other being used in the template.

`GridComponent.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-grid',
  template: './grid.component.html',
  exportAs: 'myGrid'
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private grid_renderer: Renderer2, private grid_el: ElementRef) {}

 @Input() isSort = false;

 ... some other code
}
```

`GridSortingComponent.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { GridComponent  } from './grid.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'sorted-grid',
  template: '',
  exportAs: 'SortingGrid'
})
export class GridSortingComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input()
 set for(value: GridComponent) {
   if (!this._grid) {
     this_grid = value;
   }
 }
 
 constructor(@Inject(GridComponent) @Optional() private grid: GridComponent) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   if (this.grid) {
     this.grid.setDefault()
    }
 }
```

`grid.component.html`

```
<sorted-grid> *ngIf="isSort"></sorted-grid>
```

Angular says there is a circular dependency from `GridComponent --> GridSortingComponent --> GridComponent`.

Does anyone have an approach to fix this problem? The Official Doc says to use an intermediate interface or shared module but I am not too familiar with how to do so with a Injected Component and the other used in the template.

Comment: I was thinking of using the injected grid component to initialize some values and/or to get some data e.g. which rows are currently selected on the grid.

Comment: I made my comments into an answer. I think you're confusing injection with simple arguments, but maybe you just need to elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding, but it looks like you don't need injection here.
Looks like you just want to optionally pass a `GridComponent` reference to the `GridSortingComponent`. That doesn't require injection.

`GridSortingComponent.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import type { GridComponent } from './grid.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'sorted-grid',
  template: '',
  exportAs: 'SortingGrid'
})
export class GridSortingComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input()
 set grid(value: GridComponent | undefined) {
   if (!this._grid) {
     this.grid = value;
   }
 }
 
 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {
   if (this.grid) {
     this.grid.setDefault()
    }
 }
```

`grid.component.html`

```
<sorted-grid [grid]="this" *ngIf="isSort"></sorted-grid>
```

If this isn't what you're trying to do, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry I am still learning Angular so I might have some inaccurate perceptions/questions.

But if you do not inject the grid, how would ngOnInit setDefault for this.grid which does not exist? My intention is to set some default sorting settings on the Grid in the future.

Comment: Ok, well [square brackets] are the syntax for an input variable. You pass them through html. Injection is primarily used to inject services.

Comment: You have made the grid an input variable.... that's different from injection. You may want to review the docs: https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-05 & https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-06

Comment: I think my intention was to be able to call several methods from GridComponent as well, such as setting default settings with `this.grid.setDefault()` and which rows are selected potentially with a call like `this.grid.getSelectedRows()`

Comment: Yes that will work with the solution above. Albeit the design isn't great. You generally just want to pass data between components, not the components themselves. If you want shared state, it's better to use a service. https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-09. In that case, you'll be injecting a service into both components, there won't be any input variables or circular reference.

Comment: I see thanks. For `[grid]="this"` would this refer to a GridSortingComponent Instance?

Also, when `ngOnInit` is called, what does `this.grid` look at?

Comment: `grid]="this"` refers to the component instance that is using that template file, in this case a `GridComponent`. `this.grid` will look at the class property `grid`, which is defined by the setter, and initialized via the `@Input()`. ie. this will reference the component instance from the html.